# php: sql update query not working as expected

Tags: php, mysqli, sql-update

I'm using the following query

```
$mysqli->query("UPDATE `edit_users` SET `password` = \"" . hash('sha512', $_POST['change_pw_password']) . "\", `single_login_pw` = NULL WHERE `id` = \"" . $userinfo['id'] . "\"");
```

As result this changes the password for the user with the specific id, but sets single_login_pw for all users to NULL.

Any idea why all single_login_pws are set to NULL and how to solve the problem?

Edit: I also tried to use mysql_query()...it's the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `LIMIT`

```
"UPDATE `edit_users` SET `password` = '" . hash('sha512', $_POST['change_pw_password']) . "', `single_login_pw` = NULL WHERE `id` = '" . $userinfo['id'] . "' LIMIT 1"
```

I also changed your double quotes to single quotes around your strings.

Comment: Did not change anything at all.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$hash = hash('sha512', $_POST['change_pw_password']);
$uid = $userinfo['id'];
$mysqli->query("UPDATE edit_users SET password = $hash, single_login_pw = NULL WHERE id = $uid");
```